# JMeter - validate multiple elements using Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, jmeter, httpresponse, assertion

I get a XML like:

```
...
<TargetEle>12356   <TargerEle>
...
<TargetEle>123dagih   <TargerEle>
...
```

Can Xpath assertion verify whether all the values of tag "TargetEle" start with "123"?

Comment: It seems that both Xpath assertion and Xpath extractor can only match a value, but not to store all the values fulfilling the expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [starts-with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/starts-with) function:

```
//TargetEle[starts-with(text(),'123')]
```

> The starts-with checks whether the first string starts with the second string

for negating (exists tags that don't start with 123) use [not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/not)

```
//TargetEle[not(starts-with(text(),'123'))]
```

Comment: This command is to match whether the response contains a <TargetEle> with text starts with '123', but could not verify all the <TargetEle>

Comment: @Warmer for not starting use `//XPATH[not(starts-with(text(),'123'))]`